# how to generate windows executable file from erlang .beam file in windows?

Tags: erlang

I could not able to find any related stuff about converting .beam erlang compiled files to windows executable file in windows........... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Joe Armstrong has done some work on this: http://www.sics.se/~joe/sae.html

It only works for really old versions of Erlang and I don't know of anyone who has done anything similar for newer versions.